# Caliburn.Micro: Как добавить новую ViewModel( помимо MainViewModel)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Доброго времени суток.

Я пытаюсь написать приложение , используя паттерн mvvm при участии фреймворка Caliburn.Micro .Моя задача: в MainView.xaml кроме MainViewModel ещё одну вьюмодель привязать к `MenuItem` ,где `Header="Файл"`. Он описан в отдельном классе`FileMenuViewModel`. Привязку MenuItem к вьюмодели в xaml я делаю так:

```html
<MenuItem cal:View.Model="{Binding FileMenuViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Файл" Height="22" Margin="4,0,0,0">
```

, но при кликании любых кнопок менюшки из MenuItem "Файл" в форме вылетает Exception , например , такой:

"No target found for method OpenFileWindow."

Как я понимаю Caliburn Micro не может найти из этого свойства cal:View.Model этот дурацкий Target , в которой и указывается ViewModel или любой другой элемент , который привязывается к View.

Вот мой проект:

https://yadi.sk/d/Z9paO0yfuqwWc

Столько гуглил и все равно не нахожу:
почему CaliBurn.Micro не может найти Target и как это исправить ?

Прошу помогите(и не нападайте , плиз)))) ) , только пока ещё не предлагайте мне варианты , при которых мне придётся AppBootStrapper унаследовать от класса Bootstrapper , что придётся брать ещё с либы Silverlight или Prism , с чем я пока абсолютно не хочу иметь дело (итак тяжело мне в учёбе).

Comment: Если вам тяжело в учёбе, почему вы не пишете на стоковом WPF? Там всё проще.

Comment: (У нас из разбирающихся в Caliburn.Micro, видимо, только @Squidward.)

Comment: @VladD ,как бы да , но один парень , к которому я обращался за помощью , говорит , что wpf средствами CaliBurn Micro проще. В том плане , что вообще это исключает необходимость объявлять события и обработчики этих событий , реализовывать интерфейс IPropertyChanged и.т.д. вручную. Но кто мог знать , что чтобы добавить ещё одну дополнительную вьюмодель помимо MainViewMode, нужно лезть в класс AppBootStrapper и оттуда объявлять дополнительные вьюмодели , что с одной стороны так не удобно. А  , кроме юзанья ещё и сторонний BootStrapper<IShell> или чтото в этом роде , доки не говорят как ещё можно.

Comment: Ну, вы видите, что проще в одном — сложнее в другом :) Подождём квалифицированных отвечающих.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается Caliburn.Micro действительно устанавливает общую для всех компонентов формы(юзерконтрола) определённого окна класс вьюмодели , которую указывают и вызывают через конструктор класса AppBootStrapper. Чтобы поменять вьюмодель у юзерконтрола , нужно менять свойство контекста данных по отношению к тому тегу контрола(компонента формы) , где он применяется для вашей новой вьюмодели. Таким образом , чтобы задать новую модель , класс которой определён , нужно написать следующим образом:

```html
<Grid.DataContext>
      <VModels:TextInOutViewModel />
</Grid.DataContext>
```

, где VModels - псевдоним , указывающий на пространство имён , где вы храните обычно классы , каждый из которых представляет вьюмодель